# YouTubePlayerView FullScreen wrong

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

My App play video on `youtube`, I want to make drag feature as **Youtube** so that I put `YouTubePlayerView` on `DraggablePannel`.

https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel/

FullScreenControllFlag: `YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT`

However when I click FullScreen YouTubePlayerView hidden.

What is my wrong here ?

Layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffe8f2fe"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/checkInternet"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/no_internet"
            android:textSize="@dimen/bodyTextSize" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleInverse"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <GridView
                android:id="@id/gridView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.github.pedrovgs.DraggableView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:draggable_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/draggable_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        draggable_view:bottom_view_id="@+id/listV_main"
        draggable_view:enable_minimized_horizontal_alpha_effect="false"
        draggable_view:top_view_height="200dp"
        draggable_view:top_view_id="@+id/youtube_id"
        draggable_view:top_view_margin_bottom="10dp"
        draggable_view:top_view_margin_right="10dp"
        draggable_view:top_view_resize="true"
        draggable_view:top_view_x_scale_factor="2.3"
        draggable_view:top_view_y_scale_factor="2.3">

        <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
            android:id="@id/youtube_id"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@id/listV_main"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1.0" />

    </com.github.pedrovgs.DraggableView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I suggest you also post what you coded so far so we can determine 'what is your wrong there'.

Comment: Put your YouTubePlayerView below the ListView

Comment: on DraggableView I have    draggable_view:bottom_view_id="@+id/listV_main"
 draggable_view:top_view_id="@+id/youtube_id", I portrait mode YouTubePlayerView  abover ListView. But when I click fullscreen only show ListView.

Comment: If you think you did everything correctly, i suggest you contact the owner of the library you are using. (com.github.pedrovgs.DraggableView)

Comment: hello. same issue with you :((. i still can not find real answer

Comment: @MsBao Please add your complete code to determine where problems occurs